# Characters missing when running Ubuntu (security onion)/xMing

Tags: ubuntu, characters, xming

I have problems with some characters. 
I am running Security Onion (which is an Ubuntu variant) through xming.
Characters 
1 2 3 4 w e r t f m
Are not working. All others (to my knowledge) work which includes ! " # ¤ W E R T F M
Funnliy, just after launching xming, everything works fine for some seconds.

Also, all characters work fine when logging in locally.
It is a virtual installation (vSphare)

It is really frustrating and I have no idea what the problem is....

BR
Erik